# php array does not increment properly.

Tags: php

in my php code I run a bunch of shell scripts that finally output the following

```
['October 20, 2003', '047085815X', '978-\n0470858158', '1', u'\nWireless Foresight: Scenarios of the Mobile World in 2015 [Hardcover]\n']
```

the above output is saved to $temp.

However, when I do echo $temp[0] it prints the first open bracket and echo $temp[1] print the single quote mark etc.....

I believe this is because its a string and not an array.

I would like to convert this to n array were each element is separated with a coma.

However, note that october 20, 2003 has a comma in it and that should remain its own element.

Can someone point me to what function im looking for.

Comment: What is the `u` before the string in array position `4`?

Comment: Have a look at str_getcsv in the php manual http://nz1.php.net/str_getcsv

Answer (score 2):

trim the opening and closing [], then use [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: Welp.. much better than mine; +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the function you're looking for

[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

quick example

```
$line = "'October 20, 2003', '047085815X', '978-\n0470858158', '1', '\nWireless     Foresight: Scenarios of the Mobile World in 2015 [Hardcover]\n'";

$parsed = str_getcsv(
  $line, # Input line
  ",",   # Delimiter
  "'"   # Enclosure
);

print_r($parsed);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => October 20, 2003 [1] => 047085815X [2] => 978- 0470858158 [3] => 1 [4] => Wireless Foresight: Scenarios of the Mobile World in 2015 [Hardcover] )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have appears to be closer to a javascript array.  I don't know how your shell script works, but I do know how php arrays are formed; you need the following to form a php array:

```
$temp = array('item1','item2','etc');
```

So for you, I'd output the following, minus the square brackets:

```
$temp = array('October 20, 2003', '047085815X', '978-\n0470858158', '1', '\nWireless Foresight: Scenarios of the Mobile World in 2015 [Hardcover]\n');
```

And then $temp[0] will return the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Your input looks very much like a js array, except for the mysterious `u` symbol staying outside of the single quotes, which every other answer seems to ignore. So will I. If you change your single quotes to double quotes, you'll be able to use `json_decode` function to get a **php** array from the js one.

```
$str = '["October 20, 2003", "047085815X", "978-\n0470858158", "1", "\nWireless Foresight: Scenarios of the Mobile World in 2015 [Hardcover]\n"]';
print_r(json_decode($str));
```